# Get result of prepared mysqli query in an array instead of binding vars to fields

Tags: php, mysqli

This yields proper results, but I would like to have the resulting row in an array, instead of binding individual variables to each field, so I can access fields like `$row[0]` and/or `$row["name"]`.

```
    $idToSearch = 2;

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "db_people");

    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, age from People where id = ?");
    $statement->bind_param("i", $idToSearch);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($name, $age);

    if($statement->fetch()) {
        echo "The name is $name and the age is $age. ";
    } else {
        echo "No person found with that id.";
    }
```

Saw an example about fetch_assoc(), but it used a mysqli_result class which I don't know hot to use and unprepared statements which I'd rather not use.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm fine with a solution whether it uses bind_result or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use fetch_assoc you would need to use get_results which would force you to not use the bind which it seems you don't want to do. So I believe what you want to do is explained pretty well by user [uramihsayibok](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#92505) in the php docs for the bind_result function, specifically here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#92505. They explain how to work around that in order get the results into an array.

Comment: To clarify, I'm fine with a solution whether it uses bind_result or not. Reading that comment, are `fetch_assoc` and `fetch_array` still not implemented for prepared statements?

Comment: @wilf They are implemented but you would replace `$statement->bind_result($name, $age);` with `$results = $statement->get_results();` and then you would do `$row = $results->fetch_assoc();` which will THEN return you the stuff as an assoc array. So in short, it can be used with prepared statements but the stuff after the execute is different.

Comment: Yep, I just gotta update php since apparently `mysqli_stmt::get_result` is only in 5.3 or newer :c

Comment: In addition to that get_result will only work if you have mysqlnd - native driver -  installed/enabled. Unfortunately this is not the case with MAMP, so I am still looking for an alternative to bind results, which can be very cumbersome with multiple columns. Also, I saw nowhere that binding results adds any benefits whatsoever.